# Script to delete text files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I was trying to make a script that searches for all ASCII text files in the directory that you point out and after that writes the path of every file to a text file. After that it's supposed to show the head of each file one by one and ask if you want to delete the file. If you say yes it removes that file, if you say something else it just shows you the next file and etc. until you check every file.
So I've ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Give directory to search for ASCII text files"
read direct
find $direct -type f -exec file {} + | grep ASCII > ztextz
sed "s/ .*//" ztextz > ztextz1
sed "s/://g" ztextz1 > ztextz2
#until here everything works fine
#it creates the file that contains paths of all ASCII text files in the directory given by you
#After that it is a mess..it needs to check the head of every file one by one
#and let me decide if I want to delete it or not
files=ztextz2
while IFS= read -r name;
do
head "$name";

echo "Do you want to delete this file?"
read want
case $want in
YES)
rm $name;;
Yes)
rm $name;;
yes)

rm $name;;
Y)
rm $name;;
y)
rm $name;;
esac
done < "$files"
```

So as the output I suppose to see 10 lines from first text file in my dir and question if I want to remove that file. After I respond with "Yes" it is supposed to remove that file and show me the 10 lines from next file and etc.

The output that I get now is the first 10 lines from 2 files (I have 4 files in my dir) and the question "Do you want to delete this file?" and then the script breaks.

Seems like its not working as expected. Could someone please explain me where my mistake is?

---

**OK since I don't have enough reputation to answer myself I put it here.**

---

Yeah so I've sticked with my old script where I got problem with putting two $$ together like $$numb and replaced them with ${!numb} it started to work...so now I can clean my directories from the text files that I don't need with that script=)

```
   #!/bin/bash
echo "Give directory to search for ASCII text files"
read direct
find $direct -type f -exec file {} + | grep ASCII > ztextz
sed "s/ .*//" ztextz > ztextz1
sed "s/://g" ztextz1 > ztextz2
set `less ztextz2`
numb=$#
rm ztextz*
while [ $numb -gt 0 ]
do head ${!numb}
echo "Do you want to delete ${!numb} file?"
read want
case $want in
yes)
rm ${!numb}
echo "File is removed"
sleep 1;;
Yes)
rm ${!numb}
echo "File is removed"
sleep 1;;
Y)
rm ${!numb}
echo "File is removed"
sleep 1;;
y)
rm ${!numb}
echo "File is removed"
sleep 1;;
YES)
rm ${!numb}
echo "File is removed"
sleep 1;;
esac
numb=$[$numb-1]
done
```

PS. to make it faster remove `sleep 1` =)

Comment: Please explain _how_ it is not working. I can see some problems immediately but it is much easier to answer if you clearly explain what the expected behavior is and how the actual behavior is different.

Comment: Added some information. Hope it is a bit more clear now

Comment: Why don't you use `rm -i` instead of asking all those question?

Comment: @unxnut why not adding it as an answer - I'd happily upvote it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading the file with **two** instances of `read` - one for reading the filename the other one for getting the answer. Hence the `read` waiting for the answer eats every second filename, and you should hope the filelist doesn't look like:

```
some_throuwaway_stuff
foo
very_important_file.txt
Yes
some_throuwaway_stuff
foo
```

Your script should probably look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Give directory to search for ASCII text files"
read direct
exec 3<&0
find "$direct" -type f |
while IFS= read -r name; do
    echo "========================================"
    if file "$name" | grep ASCII; then
        echo "----------------------------------------"
        head "$name";
        echo "----------------------------------------"
        echo "Do you want to delete this file?"
        read -u 3 want
        case $want in
            YES|Yes|yes|Y|y)
                rm "$name"
                ;;
            *)
                ;;
        esac
    fi
done
```

Notice the redirection `exec 3<&0` which will feed regular `stdin` to file descriptor 3, which is then checked in the cycle for answer from the user.

That said, `rm -i` is likely a better option.

Comment: better is the change `rm` to `rm -f`

Comment: Depends on circumstances. `rm` has many useful options that can be either beneficial or wreak havoc on your data depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your block

```
while [ $numb -gt 0 ]
    do head ${!numb}
    echo "Do you want to delete ${!numb} file?"
    read want
    case $want in
        yes)
            rm ${!numb}
            echo "File is removed"
            sleep 1;;
        Yes)
            rm ${!numb}
            echo "File is removed"
            sleep 1;;
        Y)
            rm ${!numb}
            echo "File is removed"
            sleep 1;;
        y)
            rm ${!numb}
            echo "File is removed"
            sleep 1;;
        YES)
            rm ${!numb}
            echo "File is removed"
            sleep 1;;
    esac
    numb=$[$numb-1]
done
```

by

```
while [ $numb -gt 0 ]
do
    head ${!numb}
    rm -i ${!numb}
    numb=$[$numb-1]
done
```